# redirecting back message

Tags: php, smarty

I have a document called `editprofile.php` and I have another one that is called `action.php`. when the user submits their info using `editprofile.php`. the information get `POST`ed to `action.php` where I process the information and send it to mysql. After sending it I want to show a message that everything has been successfully changed. I used this :

```
if $everythingisdone{
$smarty->assign('sucess', 'Your changes have been made');
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

I get redirected to the previous page, but there is no message even though I have this in my `editprofile.tpl`

```
{if $sucess}
<div class="sucess">
{$sucess}
</div>
{/if}
```

how can I assign the message when I redirect back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
//custom smarty function to set session flash messages
function smarty_function_set_flash($params, $smarty) {
    $flash = "";
    if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
        $flash = $_SESSION['success'];
        $_SESSION['success'] = ""; //unset the session
    }
    return $flash; //return flash message
}
```

your code

```
....
if($everythingisdone) {
  $_SESSION['success'] =  'Your changes have been made';
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

and view:

```
{if isset($smarty.session.flash) && $smarty.session.flash != ''}
    <div class="sucess">{set_flash}</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: does the function run every time somebody visit the page? will this effect the server speed or anything?

Comment: @shnisaka no it wont affect the server speed so much that you need to re-think about it... and this function will only run in case you have session flash message..

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to another page and expect variables to persist. When you call `$smarty->assign()` that change will persist only for that specific page request and no more, once you redirect its all gone.

You could do this with a GET parameter:

```
<?php
// action.php
if ($something) {
    header ("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?success=1");
    die;
}
else {
    header ("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?success=0");
    die;
}
```

Then in `editprofile.php` you could check for that value:

```
<?php
// editprofile.php
if ($_GET['success'] == '1') {
    // yes!
}
else {
    // aww :(
}
```

This would not be necessary if you wouldn't redirect like that. Why not have the form on the `editprofile.php` and submit it to the same page and check for errors there? Set a flag variable and show an error message if the form did not submit:

```
<?php
if ($ok) {
    $smarty->assign ('form_processed', true); 
}
else {
    $smarty->assign ('form_processed', false); 
}
```

Then simply use that in your form to check for an error.

Hope this helps